# How to configure SVM in the last layer of CNN in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, svm

I came across [this](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Etang/papers/dlsvm.pdf) paper on "Deep Learning using Support Vector Machines". After watching [this](https://youtu.be/upo34AT1Cys?si=2WkHjsomX1jawj8y&t=521) youtube tutorial, I tried to implement it in my model which is being trained on FER2013 dataset for facial human expression recognition.

Model:
[Kaggle notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/wolgwang/tests?scriptVersionId=162405664)

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    
    layers.Reshape((48, 48, 1), input_shape=(2304,)),
    
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu' ),
    layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),
    
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'),
    layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),
    
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'),
    layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),
    
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'),
    layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),
    
    layers.Flatten(),
    
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.3),
    
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.3),
    
    layers.Dense(7, kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01),activation
             ='softmax')
])

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss = 'squared_hinge',
    metrics=['accuracy'],
)
```

But this is giving unexpected results:

```
Epoch 47/50
202/202 [==============================] - 4s 19ms/step - loss: 0.3469 - accuracy: 0.1308 - val_loss: 0.3508 - val_accuracy: 0.1299
Epoch 48/50
202/202 [==============================] - 4s 19ms/step - loss: 0.3469 - accuracy: 0.1326 - val_loss: 0.3508 - val_accuracy: 0.1378
Epoch 49/50
202/202 [==============================] - 4s 19ms/step - loss: 0.3469 - accuracy: 0.1617 - val_loss: 0.3508 - val_accuracy: 0.2426
Epoch 50/50
202/202 [==============================] - 4s 19ms/step - loss: 0.3469 - accuracy: 0.1594 - val_loss: 0.3508 - val_accuracy: 0.1291
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How to fix this?

Comment: Where is SVM in your code?

Comment: @Reza I am using squared hinge loss with L2 regulariser.

Comment: try smaller a learning rate and L2 regularization (0.001)

Comment: @Reza It didn't work. Same results.

Comment: From the [docs for squared hinge loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SquaredHinge) `y_true values are expected to be -1 or 1` but you have class labels from 0 to 6.

Comment: @u1234x1234 Thanks. That answers what is wrong. But how to implement DLSVM as given in research paper?